# Weyl Type Lemma

Tags: analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis, exponential-sums

I was referred to Lemma 3.18 of an old Bourgain [paper](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.158/bourgain-restriction.pdf) (pg. 122) concerning weighted exponential sums and I am having trouble understanding the proof. I have reproduced below for convenience.

> **Lemma.** Let $\{\sigma_{n}\}$ be a multiplier satisfying
>
> 1. $0\leq \sigma_{n}\leq 1$, $\sigma_{n}=1$ on $[-N,N]$,
> 2. $\{\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}\}$ is bounded by $\frac{1}{N}$ and has variation bounded by $\frac{1}{N}$
> 3. $\text{supp}(\sigma_{n})\subset [-2N,2N]$.
>      and let $f(x,t)=\sum\sigma_{n}e(nx+n^{2}t)$. If $0<a<q<N$, $(a,q)=1$ and $\|t-\frac{a}{q}\|<\frac{1}{qN}$, then
>      $$|f(x,t)|\lesssim \frac{N}{\sqrt{q}(1+N\|t-\frac{a}{q}\|^{1/2})}$$
>      (Above, $e(z):=e^{2\pi i z}$ and $\|\cdot\|$ denotes distance to nearest integer.)

So according to the lemma, we should be able to improve the quadratic Weyl bound $\frac{N}{\sqrt{q}}$ that one can find in Iwaniec and Martin, if $\|t-\frac{a}{q}\|$ is "large".

*Edit:* As Fedja pointed out, the variation condition is that $\sum_{n}|\sigma_{n+2}+\sigma_{n}-2\sigma_{n+1}|\lesssim\frac{1}{N}$.

We proceed by consider $|f(x,t)|^{2}$ and making a change of variable to get

$$|f(x,t)|^{2}\lesssim\sum_{l}|\sum_{k\equiv l\pmod{2}}\sigma_{\frac{k+l}{2}}\sigma_{\frac{l-k}{2}}e(k(x+lt))|\tag{1}$$

Following Bourgain, write $k=2k_{1}$ if $l$ is even and $k=2k_{1}+1$ otherwise. At this point, Bourgain claims that a bound of
$$c\frac{1}{N(\|2x+2lt\|+\frac{1}{N})^{2}}$$
follows, but he does not provide any details. Presumably, there is a partial summation argument to exploit the conditions on $\{\sigma_{n}\}$. So, assume fixed $l$ is even and consider the expression

$$|\sum_{k_{1}}\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}+k_{1}}\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}-k_{1}}e(2k_{1}(x+lt))|\tag{2}$$

Note that since $\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}-k_{1}}$ has support in $[\frac{l}{2}-2N,\frac{l}{2}+2N]$ and $\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}+k_{1}}$ has support in $[-\frac{l}{2}-2N,-\frac{l}{2}+2N]$, we see that $|l|\leq 4N$ for there to be a nonzero contribution. Doing partial summation, changing variables and using the support condition on $\sigma_{n}$, we get

\begin{align*}
(2)&=|\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{4N}[\sigma_{l+k_{1}+1-2N}\sigma_{-k_{1}-1+2N}-\sigma_{l+k_{1}-2N}\sigma_{-k_{1}+2N}]\sum_{j=0}^{k_{1}}e\left(2(\frac{l}{2}-2N+j)(x+lt)\right)|\\
&\leq\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{4N}|\sigma_{l+k_{1}+1-2N}\sigma_{-k_{1}-1+2N}-\sigma_{l+k_{1}-2N}\sigma_{-k_{1}+2N}|\cdot|\sum_{j=0}^{k_{1}}e(2j(x+lt))|\\
&\leq\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{4N}\frac{2}{N}\min\{k_{1},\frac{1}{2\|2x+2lt\|}\}\\
&\lesssim\min\{2N,\frac{1}{\|2x+2lt\|}\}
\end{align*}

I don't see how to get Bourgain's bound, unless one assumes $\sum_{n}|\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}|\leq\frac{1}{N}$.

---

*Edit:* Note that if $\|2x+2lt\|<\frac{1}{N}$, then we can apply the trivial bound to obtain
$$|\sum_{k_{1}}\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}+k_{1}}\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}-k_{1}}e(k_{1}(2x+2lt))|\lesssim N=\frac{4}{N(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N})^{2}}\lesssim\frac{1}{N(\|2x+2lt\|+\frac{1}{N})^{2}}$$
So assume that $\|2x+2lt\|\geq\frac{1}{N}$.

Instead of doing partial summation once, following Fedja's very helpful suggestions we apply partial summation twice to exploit the variation condition on $\{\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}\}$. Define $e_{0}:=1$ and $e_{k_{1}}:=e(k_{1}(2x+2lt))-e(-k_{1}(2x+2lt))$, for $k_{1}\geq 1$. Set $\tau_{k_{1}}^{(l)}:=\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}+k_{1}}\sigma_{\frac{l}{2}-k_{1}}$, and observe that each $\tau^{(l)}$ is a multiplier satisfying the conditions of the lemma (up to a constant factor). We  write (2) as
\begin{align*}
(2)&=|\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N}\tau_{k_{1}}^{(l)}e_{k_{1}}|\\
&=|\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-1}[\underbrace{\tau_{j+1}^{(l)}-\tau_{j}^{(l)}}_{:=\Delta_{j}\tau^{(l)}}]\underbrace{\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{j}e_{k_{1}}}_{:=E(j)}|\\
&=|\underbrace{\Delta_{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-1}\tau^{(l)}}_{=0}\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-1}E(j)-\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-2}[\Delta_{j+1}\tau^{(l)}-\Delta_{j}\tau^{(l)}]\sum_{k=0}^{j}E(k)|\\
&=|\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-2}[\tau_{j+2}^{(l)}-2\tau_{j+1}^{(l)}+\tau_{j}^{(l)}]\dfrac{\sin^{2}((j+1)\pi(2x+2lt))}{\sin^{2}(\pi(2x+2lt))}| \tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we obtain the ultimate equality by using the well-known trigonometric identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{j}\sum_{|m|\leq k}e(m(2x+2lt))=\dfrac{\sin^{2}((j+1)\pi(2x+2lt))}{\sin^{2}(\pi(2x+2lt))}$$
To estimate (3), we use the fact that $|\sin \pi\alpha|\geq 2\|\alpha\|$ for any real $\alpha$, to obtain
$$(3)\lesssim\frac{1}{\|2x+2lt\|^{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{|l|}{2}+4N-2}|\tau_{j+2}^{(l)}-2\tau_{j+1}^{(l)}+\tau_{j}^{(l)}|\lesssim\frac{1}{N\|2x+2lt\|^{2}}$$
Since $\|2x+2lt\|\geq\frac{1}{N}$, we see that
$$\frac{1}{N\|2x+2lt\|^{2}}=\frac{2}{N(\|2x+2lt\|+\|2x+2lt\|)^{2}}\lesssim\frac{1}{N(\|2x+2lt\|+\frac{1}{N})^{2}}$$

Comment: Apparently, the words "has variation..." also apply to the difference sequence. This makes sense from the viewpoint of English grammar but I'm too sleepy now to see if this interpretation is mathematically sound too :-)

Comment: @fedja: Thanks for your comment. If the variation of a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is defined by $\sum_{n}|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$, then applying this definition to the difference sequence yields $\sum_{n}|\sigma_{n+2}-2\sigma_{n+1}+\sigma_{n}|$. I'm not sure what example of such a multiplier is. I really want to to apply the lemma with $\sigma_{n}$ given by Littlewood-Paley projections.

Comment: @fedja: But even if you relax $\sup_{n}|\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}|\leq\frac{1}{N}$ to $\lesssim\frac{1}{N}$, then you can take $\phi(x)$ to be a bump function $1$ on $[-1,1]$ with support in $[-2,2]$. Set $\sigma_{n}:=\phi(x/N)$. Clearly, $|\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}|\lesssim\frac{1}{N}$. By the FTC,
$$|\sigma_{n+2}-2\sigma_{n+1}-\sigma_{n}|=\frac{1}{N}|\int_{0}^{1}[\phi'(\frac{n+1+t}{N})-\phi'(\frac{n+t}{N})]dt|\lesssim\frac{1}{N^2}$$
It's not clear to me how to satisfy the condition in my previous comment. Also, it's not clear to me how one would use that condition in the proof of the lemma.

Comment: The second difference of order $1/N^2$ gives the variation of order $1/N$ (we have $N$ of them), so this part looks fine. Also, Bourgain, like any analyst, never distinguishes between $A \le B$ and $A\le Const\,B$ unless some subtraction of quantities of the same order of magnitude is involved, so you are quite safe to assume that all inequalities are up to a constant factor. As to what use it is, I have to take a close look so I'll try to comment on it later unless somebody beats me to it.

Comment: @fedja: Ah, yes you are right about the variation! I forgot about the support condition.

Comment: If you look at the continuous analogue of $(2)$ and assume that your $\sigma$ comes from a $C^2$ multiplier, you will see that in order to get the quadratic decay required, you will need to integrate by parts ***twice*** (but then it is OK). So, apparently, you are to use the Abel's partial summation trick twice as well before putting the absolute values around the terms. I will abstain from writing the corresponding monstrous expressions, but it should work and the second difference summability condition should be just right (the second derivative in $L^1$)

Comment: @fedja: Thanks. When I do the second application of Abel's trick, I need to estimate $|\int E(u)du|$, where $E(u):=\sum_{0\leq k_{1}\leq u}e(k_{1}(2x+2lt))$, which is something like $|\sum_{k_{1}=0}^{u}(u-k_{1}+1)e(k_{1}(2x+2lt))|$. The best bound I can come up with for this expression is $\min\{N^{2},\frac{N}{\|2x+2lt\|}\}$, which destroys the gain from the second difference summability condition.

Comment: Erm... How about combining $k_1$ and $-k_1$ first? Then you  get the Fejer kernel, which is certainly decaying quadratically, isn't it?

Comment: Look at how you are squaring the sum. Depending on the way you look at it, you either have the differences running over both positive and negative integers, or you have a sum of squares plus ***twice the real part*** of sums like you wrote with $k_1$ running from $1$ to $u$. In both cases, you end up with the Fejer kernel. ($|\sum_{k=1}^u a_k|^2=\sum_{h=-u}^u\sum_{k\in I_h}a_k\bar a_{k+h}=\sum_{k}|a_k|^2+\pmb{2\Re}\sum_{h=1}^u\sum_{k\in I_h}a_k\bar a_{k+h}$)